# Display records on week format

Tags: php, mysql

I have data stored in datetime format, like this

```
dtime               | one | two | three

2018-01-01 17:52:15 | 1   | 5   | 8
2018-01-02 17:52:15 | 3   | 0   | 6
2018-01-03 17:52:15 | 2   | 3   | 5
2018-01-04 17:52:15 | 7   | 0   | 9
2018-01-05 17:52:15 | 0   | 3   | 1
2018-01-06 17:52:15 | 3   | 6   | 8
2018-01-08 17:52:15 | 7   | 2   | 2
2018-01-09 17:52:15 | 3   | 1   | 5
2018-01-10 17:52:15 | 7   | 6   | 1
2018-01-11 17:52:15 | 5   | 8   | 2
2018-01-12 17:52:15 | 4   | 0   | 1
2018-01-13 17:52:15 | 9   | 7   | 2
2018-01-15 17:52:15 | 2   | 4   | 1
```

I want to display it Week-wise.

```
Week1                        Week2 
Monday    | 1 | 5 | 8  
Tuesday   | 3 | 0 | 6
Wednesday | 2 | 3 | 5
Thursday  | 7 | 0 | 9
Friday    | 0 | 3 | 1
Saturday  | 3 | 6 | 8
```

Like this. 
I tried using WEEK(dtime) in my query. But could't get the result.

Comment: please attach your query that u have tried so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT WEEK(dtime) AS week, DAYOFWEEK(dtime) AS dow, one, two, three
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY dtime ASC
```

Once the data is extracted, you can manipulate it with `PHP` into the shape you prefer.

Comment: Thanks a ton, this is exactly what i was trying to do. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

This may help you:

`DAYNAME()` gives name:

```
SELECT
  WEEK(dtime, 1) AS weekno,
  DAYNAME(dtime) AS weekday,
  one,
  two,
  three
FROM members
ORDER BY dtime ASC
```

[image]